# UnicodeEncodeError printing Hangul characters in the terminal

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, python-module-unicodedata

This application runs on a mac only and I'm stuck with Python 2.

I have an input string '한글' which when decoded through an [online unicode converter](https://www.branah.com/unicode-converter) shows as \u1112\u1161\u11ab\u1100\u1173\u11af

For my application to work, I need to convert this somehow to '한글', shown as \ud55c\uae00.

I believe I need to normalise to NFC.

I've tried

```
unicodedata.normalize('NFC', myString)
```

but I get the following:

```
TypeError: normalize() argument 2 must be unicode, not str
```

I've tried

```
unicodeMyString = myString.decode('utf-8', 'ignore')
unicodedata.normalize('NFC', unicodeMyString)
```

but I get the following:

```
ERROR: Code 1: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "code.py", line 222, in <module>
    sys.stdout.write(unicodedata.normalize('NFC', unicodeMyString))  
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Is there any way to convert in Python 2? Thanks!

SOLVED:

> The problem isn't normalising, it's printing it to the terminal - python2 tries to encode the output to ASCII. Does PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8 python myscript.py work? – snakecharmerb 20 mins ago

Comment: Why not install python3 on your Mac?

Comment: @Roy2012 Unfortunately I can't ask other people who use my application to install python3 first and it can't be bundled with it

Comment: Please show the full traceback of the last error as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: The problem isn't normalising, it's printing it to the terminal - python2 tries to encode the output to ASCII.  Does `PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8 python myscript.py` work?

Comment: @snakecharmerb It does work indeed by adding what you said there. Thank you for solving this - I hadn't expected that to be why it was failing, makes sense now!